# Ignoring constraints when creating open generic type using reflection

Tags: c#, generics, reflection, mono

I work on a code that compares structures of classes in C# as a part of a serialization library.

I stumbled upon a problem with the particular generic class setup:

```
class B<Y> where Y: B<Y> {}
class A<X>: B<A<X>> {}
```

I already have objects of type `Type` that represents *open* generic type `B<>` and *open* generic type `A<>`. Now I would like to create *open* generic type `B<A<>>` that I will use as a template for other *closed* generic types. In order to do that I tried using `MakeGenericType` method:

```
typeof(B<>).MakeGenericType(typeof(A<>))
```

but it ended up with an exception about "Invalid generic arguments". It makes sense as type `A<>` does not meet a constraint of `Y` generic argument.

I know that I can obtain the type I want by calling `typeof(A<>).BaseType`, but it does not fit the flow of my algorithm and seems not to be a general solution to the problem. My question is: is there a way to create an *open* type `B<A<>>` **ignoring/deferring** constraint check to the moment of creating a *closed* version of it?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of - I suspect that the use of such an ability would be *so* niche that it's not worth it being available in the API.

Comment: I've copied your code to run it and it just works fine for me. Resulting in `B\`1[A\`1[X]]`. https://dotnetfiddle.net/qR9uAs

Comment: @thehennyy Thanks! You are right. It works fine, but... not on Mono. I failed to mention it in my question and failed to test the code on .NET before posting it.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the comment of @thehennyy, I verified it is a bug in Linux Mono 4.8.0. I reported it [here](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=54485) and wait for a reaction.